# How to check whether a value in a key is same for all inner arrays

Tags: php, arrays

array will look like

```
array(
    "0" => array(
        "name" => "abc",
        "age" => 10
    )
    "1" => array(
        "name" => "def",
        "age" => 10
    )
)
```

I need to check whether all ages are same in php

Comment: What you have tried so far?
 Post your attempts too.

Comment: `(count(array_unique(array_colum($myArray, 'age'))) == 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check like this:

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    "0"=>array(
      "name"=>"abc",
      "age"=>10,
    ),
    "1"=>array(
      "name"=>"def",
      "age"=>10,
    )
);

if(count($arr)) {
  if(count(array_unique(array_column($arr, 'age'))) > 1 && count($arr) > 0) {
    echo "Array contains different ages";
  } else {
    echo "Array contains same ages";
  }
} else {
    echo "Array has no ages";
}
```

Output:

```
Array contains same ages
```

Here is the [eval](https://eval.in/566540). Try out there!